# Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'folder/other_folder'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to use navigation in angular 2, I have this structure:

```
--src
    --app
    --pages
        --home
            --home.component.ts
```

My app.routes.ts is like this

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../pages/home/home.component';
export const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: '../pages/home', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

What is good? the empty path, I check de base in the index.

What is wrong? **the second path, when I clicked the option, give me the error I describe**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this second route definition?

Comment: The idea is use different pages, but first I want to make it works, when I call another page, under pages folder, the error is the same :( @JBNizet

Comment: Even if that was possible, why would you want the URL of a page to be `http://somehost.com/../pages/home`?

Comment: I'm rellaing trying to arrive to the HomeComponent file, I just have to remove the dots? @JBNizet

Comment: Again, what are you trying to achieve? The path of the route isn't supposed to point to any file or anything. It's just the path you **want** to assign to some page of your application. So if you want the contacts page to be displayed at http://somehost.com/contacts, then you use the path 'contacts'. If you instead want it displayed at http://somehost.com/friends, then you use the path 'friends'. So, what are you trying to achieve with '../pages/home'? Why do you want to display the home page at two different URLs?